# Testing focus with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, integration-testing, capybara

I have a simple `link_to_function` in my view template

```
<%= link_to_function "add new category", "$('#category_name').focus()" %>
```

and I want to test this with capybara using request specs. Basically the spec should look something like this

```
it "focuses category form when I click 'add new category'" do
  visit new_article_path
  click_link "add new category"

  # unfortunately there's nothing like 'has_focus?'
  find_field("category_name").should have_focus  
end
```

the problem is, **I wasn't able to find anything, that would check if the element has focus.** 
The only thing I did find was this

```
page.evaluate_script('document.focus')[:id]
```

which however isn't supported by the `capybara-wekbit` driver, which I'm using to avoid opening browser for each test run.

Answer (score 31):

I just used the following code (with phantomjs driver, but I believe that it works with webkit also):

```
page.evaluate_script("document.activeElement.id") == "some_id"
```

P.S. One year question without an answer. Should they give me a badge? :)

Comment: Very helpful; you certainly deserve a badge.  Thanks.

Comment: If the actual `activeElement` is actually inserted into the dom asynchronously this method won't work as it is not necessarily already in a dom (thus can be focussed). So another check if the element is in the dom already must be added.

Comment: I've found it helpful to use `page.evaluate_script('document.activeElement').path == element.path` since the focused element doesn't always have an ID.

Comment: Comparing them directly works for me (chrome driver): `expect(evaluate_script("document.activeElement")).to eq(find_field("Foo"))`

Answer (score 9):

You should use the `:focus` selector, e.g:

```rb
page.should have_selector('#category_name:focus')
```

Comment: CSS would suggest this, but it seems Capybara/Poltergeist does not handle the :focus selector correctly. I always get an empty result for ':focus', even when document.activeElement tells me it has the correct HTMLInputElement focussed.

Answer (score 7):

With the Selenium driver you can get the focused element:

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.active_element
```

Then you can do what you like with it

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.active_element.send_keys "some text"
```

Note that it returns a `Selenium::WebDriver::Element` whereas `find` returns a `Capybara::Node::Element` so be careful when comparing them

```
expect(page.driver.browser.switch_to.active_element).to eql(find('#some-element').native)
```